# save database UserID from linked ODBC to Access

Tags: oracle, odbc, ms-access-2007, user-identification

I have an Access 2007 database with tables linked to Oracle through ODBC. I need to record the UserID of the person logging in to Oracle through the ODBC connection since it can be different from PC user. Is there any simple way how to do that? I tried a pass-through query (current_user) with no luck so far.

Comment: Is that "other database" a Microsoft SQL Server database?

Comment: Thanks for replay. Yes driver is Microsoft ODBC for Oracle 2.575.113.00. In query ODBC ConnectStr I entered ODBC;DSN=MyDSN;SERVER=MyServer; which was really picked by default.I'm getting error 923 ODBC call failed(keyword not fond where expected .. and I'm lost since I've got no experience with this. If they happy with PC login it's easy ... no such luck.

Comment: Have you tried a pass-through query like `select sys_context('USERENV','SESSION_USER') from dual` ...?

Comment: !!! GOT IT. Took me a while, why I didn't ask..... Thank you very much!

Comment: Good to hear. Was that Oracle query sufficient or did you have to tweak it a bit? (It has been a long time since I worked with Oracle.)

Comment: SELECT 
(USER_ID),(USER_PERS_NO),(sys_context('USERENV','OS_USER'))
FROM
PROD.USER_TBL
WHERE
((USER_ID)=(sys_context ('USERENV','SESSION_USER')))

Comment: sorry Gord I was away for a while. I get PC and Oracle names together now and I had to add table to get also Number because I record only user number which is link to the other tables. Works well. now I relised that Oracle doesn't support Key No like access so I have to somehow set up append query to transfer data from access to Oracle table and same time create unique key No. Since multiple stations will append data I'm not too sure :-) Entries are for supply stock from store and Store will use other end to create Pick no and deliver stock, so bit messy I guess. Anyway, thanks for your help.